# Order by time of a Datetime field in django

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

I wanted to order a query set on the basis of a time of a datetime field.
I have used the following (here Tasks is my model and datetime is the field)

```
Tasks.objects.all().order_by('datetime.time')
```

this doesn't work and also

```
Tasks.objects.all().order_by('datetime__time')
```

doesn't work as it is part of the same model.
I tried using `.annotate()` but I don't know how exactly to do it.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Tasks.objects.all().order_by('datetime__hour')
```

or

```
Tasks.objects.all().order_by('datetime__minute')
```

Comment: My field name is time. I get the following error `Cannot resolve keyword u'hours' into field. Join on 'time' not permitted.` when I try to include `.order_by(time__hours)` in my model manager as `def get_queryset(self):
  return super(TaskManager, self).get_queryset().order_by('time__hours')
`

Comment: what help do you need, you need to add another question for that

Comment: why is it not working in the model manager as `.order_by('time__hours')` ?

Comment: its not hours bro, its hour and minute and second

Comment: i even tried `__hour` bro. It says - `
Cannot resolve keyword u'hour' into field. Join on 'time' not permitted.`

Comment: added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901991/cannot-order-by-time-using-model-manager)

Answer (score 2):

```
Task.objects.all().order_by('datetime__hour', 'datetime__minute')
```

Comment: My field name is time. I get the following error `Cannot resolve keyword u'hours' into field. Join on 'time' not permitted.` when I try to include `.order_by(time__hours)` in my model manager as `def get_queryset(self):
  return super(TaskManager, self).get_queryset().order_by('time__hours')
`

Comment: Thanks, I was using different values for date and for time and this solved my problem to order the output based on the date and time.