# Cannot order by time using model manager

Tags: django, django-models, python-datetime

I made the following model manager

```
class TaskManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(TaskManager,self).get_queryset().order_by('time__hour')
```

But there is an error which says `Cannot resolve keyword u'hour' into field. Join on 'time' not permitted.`

My models.py looks something like this -

```
class Task(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='content')
    time = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = TaskManager()
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help how should I go about doing this.

Comment: what is your django version?

Comment: it is django 1.11.7

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do here. Why do you want to order by hour specifically? Why not just order by the full time?

Comment: ok, So I am making an application in which I need to have all objects based on the time. I am using just the time and not the entire datetime field because once new objects are added they might come on top of the queryset. So basically I am looking to order the tasks on the basis of time so that they are displayed according to the time of the day they are to be performed. The reason I used a datetime field and not the timefield because I had to find the difference of time in my application, and using a timefield there caused problems.